# apache kafka producer/consumer performance test

Tags: apache-kafka

I have some queries
1.the producer should send only max of 50kb
2.the consumer should fetch max of 50 messages per sec
3. how to restrict the throughput level of producer and consumer
these are all should be tested in kafka producer and consumer console
pls pour your ideas

Comment: Have you read the documentation section on quotas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? 1.the producer should send only max of 50kb ( 50 Kb in single message or 50 kb per seconds ) Do you want to know if there is any constraint or you want to implement your producer/consumer that way ?